# Is this a bug in Java SynchronizedCollection class?

Tags: java, collections

There is a internal class SynchronizedCollection - inside java.util.Collections
with two constructor. the first takes the collection and the other takes collection and a mutex.
former constructor checks argument for not being null. but the later don't!.
here is the implementation.

```
 SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c) {
        if (c==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.c = c;
        mutex = this;
  }
 SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c, Object mutex) {
        this.c = c;
        this.mutex = mutex;
 }
```

with this implementation i can break the class invariant by sending null to second
constructor.

i believe it should be something like this:

```
 SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c) {
        this(c,this)
  }
 SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c, Object mutex) {
        if (c==null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        this.c = c;
        this.mutex = mutex;
 }
```

however i can't convince myself Josh Bloch and Neal Gafter couldn't see this. so can you really tell me what i missed here?

---

edited: possible attack

```
    Map<String, String> m = new Map<String, String>(){

        @Override
        public int size() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

                   .
                   .
                   .

        @Override
        public Collection<String> values() {
            return null;
        }


    };

    Map<String, String> synchronizedMap = Collections.synchronizedMap(m);
    Collection<String> values = synchronizedMap.values();
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sure this is a bug. The both constructors should be consistent, either both should throw an exception or none should throw.

This has been fixed in Java 8. Now both constructors will throw the exception:

```
SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c) {
    this.c = Objects.requireNonNull(c);
    mutex = this;
}

SynchronizedCollection(Collection<E> c, Object mutex) {
    this.c = Objects.requireNonNull(c);
    this.mutex = Objects.requireNonNull(mutex);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both of those constructors are package protected and only the first one can possibly be used with a `null` argument through the `public` `synchronizedList()` and `synchronizedSet()` methods of `Collections`.

The other constructor is used internally (in the `Collections` class) and the first argument can never be `null` in the various implementations (calling code) so you cannot break it.

You could always try to create something in the `java.util` package but you will most likely get a `SecurityException`.

Comment: I can extends Map interface an override values() method to return null  without putting my implementation in java.util package! the object returns by values() method sends to second constructor - see Collections.synchronizedMap() and Boom!!

Comment: @MortezaAdi To be fair, that could be argued as abusing the contract of `Map.values()` which doesn't permit that behaviour explicitly. (It doesn't disallow it either, but: do you **ever** null-check the return values from `entrySet()`, `keySet()` or `values()`? Have you ever seen anyone else do so?) I'll give you that the class is lacking in robustness but there's no way to break it without actually abusing the API. I agree with Sotirios that if you could somehow cause a breakage in third-party code it'd be more of an issue.

Comment: @millimoose Maybe you right and i abused Map.values() i deliberately returned null however it may happen with careless coding too. IMHO SynchronizedCollection should and must check null argument in both constructors.

Comment: @MortezaAdi It should, because it's the right thing to do to check your preconditions / invariants, and do so explicitly instead of relying on all your callers to be correct (which is feasible for package-private code if not in general), but not because it's a plausible source of bugs.